# urlfetch doesn't always load the query in the url

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I've written some code to store some info from a website in a google spreadsheet. Because I don't want save the same object twice I need the website to order them from new to old.

This is the website i want to get info from
https://www.2dehands.be/q/lego+technic/#Language:nl-BE|sortBy:SORT_INDEX|sortOrder:DECREASING

first I tried 
`UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.2dehands.be/q/lego+technic/p/1/#sortBy:SORT_INDEX%7CsortOrder:DECREASING').getContentText();`

This is my most recent code

```
var url = 'https://www.2dehands.be/q/lego+technic/';
var options =
{
   'Language' : 'nl-BE',
   'sortBy' : 'SORT_INDEX',
   'sortOrder' : 'DECREASING',
}
var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText();
```

Sometimes I get the items listed in order and sometimes I get the sorted in the standard 'optimized' order

What could be the issue here?

Comment: The options in `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)` can't just be anything - there's a [specific list of parameters you can send](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) which are handled by Apps Script.

Comment: So I can't use the second options. But I still have the problem if I just use UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.2dehands.be/q/lego+technic/p/1/#sortBy:SORT_INDEX%7CsortOrder:DECREASING')

Comment: The issue is the URL is obfuscated with non-escaped characters like`|` and `:` which is causing problems with UrlFetchApop. The request is in fact making an API call to an endpoint which is then being loaded into the page. You can get a JSON response of the query you're looking for with a fetch to `https://www.2dehands.be/lrp/api/search?attributesByKey[]=Language%3Anl-BE&limit=30&offset=0&query=lego%20technic&sortBy=SORT_INDEX&sortOrder=DECREASING&viewOptions=list-view`.

Comment: How did you go from my link to this link?

Comment: You can see it in the request URL in the network console in your browser when you select the `Datum (nieuw-oul)` sort in the dropdown.